# Module parse failed:Unexpected token (567:17) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: vue.js, chart.js

to Load the component using bar chart in need to import chartjs to do that
i am getting this error like this

ERROR in ./node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.js
Module parse failed: D:\OnBlick Product\TechTitans\US-145602\OnBlick.ATS.Web\node_modules\chart.js\dist\chart.js Unexpected token (567:17)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

I install chartjs and create the barchart component from UI-Library
and load the barchart in the my application to do that i need to import the chartjs component
i am facing this issue like this

ERROR in ./node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.js
Module parse failed: D:\OnBlick Product\TechTitans\US-145602\OnBlick.ATS.Web\node_modules\chart.js\dist\chart.js Unexpected token (567:17)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

I am facing Some loader issue
Please help me on this